# adding switch to final link

Tags: ros, target-link-libraries, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use and external library foo.a and I was told by the manufacturer to  add -lnetpbm as a switch to your final link.  as I am getting
Linking CXX executable bin/fr_cam
/home/scott/focusrobotics/release_20120111/lib/libfrdev.a(FrImage.o): In function `FrImage': /home/scott/focusrobotics/release_20120111/src/libfrdev/FrImage.cpp:226: undefined reference to` pm_openr'

how do I do what he suggests?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12757/adding-switch-to-final-link/) by [wyosae67](https://answers.ros.org/users/1693/wyosae67/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fixed with
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} netpbm)

---

Originally posted by [wyosae67](https://answers.ros.org/users/1693/wyosae67/) with karma: 76 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1